# Can't install HP PSC 1210 DeskJet on Windows 7 32 Bit

Tags: windows-7, installation, printer

I have a HP PSC 1210 DeskJet Printer and Windows 7 32 Bit.

I am unable to install my printer properly.

Comment: Are you getting error messages when you are installing the drivers?  As of now, there's no information for anyone to go on.  The more you can provide, the better.

Comment: HP does not provide W7 drivers for that model, see this page for instructions...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01796879&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4062&product=90764&sw_lang=

Comment: If the HP instructions fail to install a print driver, then you need to upgrade the printer to one that is supported in Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try it out with installer > right click and go to 'prpoerties' .. And try to install by changing 'compatibility' mode .. Ref : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-compatibility-mode/